# Setting style in xml

Tags: android, xml, colors, background

I am trying to set the background and text color in styles.xml and have it apply to my entire application, but it does not apply to each activity at all.

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowNoTitle"> true</item>-->
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>    

</resources>
```

My **Strings.xml** includes this line:

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

Finally, my **AndroidManifest.xml** includes:

```
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Hack the World"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: apply theme in activity also like application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you change the Style for Values v11 or v14 also. v11 is the values of the api version 11, and v14 is the values of the api version 14. So make sure on which  Build Target you are compiling your project.

Comment: see my answer, you only need to create one style, the value-v11 etc. is for API specific styles.

Comment: Yes hsigmond, if may be he is compiling with Build 14 and changing his v11 . i think it will not effect the theme style. so he need to make sure that he change the style of correct Value folder.

Answer (score 2):

try this. it worked in my case...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF00FF</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a background color and text color in styles.xml for the entire application, make sure you have **not** sett the android:background attr on one of your root elements in your layout files that fills the entire layout.

```
android:background="#0000FF"
```

For your colors create a color.xml file in the value folder.

```
<resources>


  <color name="text_color_green">#00FF00</color>
  <color name="background_color_red">#4BFF0000</color>

</resources>
```

To set other text colors then the primary text color you must create some custom styles for each widgets in the style.xml file.

```
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color_red</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_green</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

    <!-- Custom style on widgets -->
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme_EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme_ButtonStyle</item>


</style>

<!-- Custom Style EditText Widget -->
<style name="AppTheme_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_color_green</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_green</item>
</style>

<!-- Custom Style Button Widget -->
<style name="AppTheme_ButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_green</item>
</style>
```

set the custom theme for the application

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- App Activities here-->

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved styles.xml in the /res/values folder of your project? As your style's parent is a predefined android theme,it should be accesible!